# Required attribute in my form is not working?I checked out similar questions

Tags: html

The required attribute is not working.Even when I am submitting an empty input,its not showing me an error.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
    EminemCircle
    </title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-image:url(e3.jpg)">
    <h1 style="color:red">Hey Come On!</h1>
    </br> </br>
    <h2 style="color:#00ff00">Dr.Dre Fires 10 million missiles!</h2>
    </br> </br>
    <form align="center" >
    <label style="color:red;font-size:35px">Email id:</label> </br>
    <input type="text"  size="40px" required /> </br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    </body>
    <html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing your code a bit. You've to change `input type="button"` to `input type="submit"` That's it.

```
    <html>
<head>
<title>
EminemCircle
</title>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(e3.jpg)">
<h1 style="color:red">Hey Come On!</h1>
</br> </br>
<h2 style="color:#00ff00">Dr.Dre Fires 10 million missiles!</h2>
</br> </br>
<form align="center" >
<label style="color:red;font-size:35px">Email id:</label> </br>
<input type="text"  size="40px" required /> </br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: An alternative would be to bind an inline `onclick` event : `<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementByTagName('form').submit();" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Well I am new to programming and people@stackoverflow are awesome!
Thanks again Akshaya!

Comment: Your welcome @MathewsMathai And if you find it useful, you may upvote the answer

Comment: I do not have enough reputation points to upvote.
@AkshayaRaghuvanshi